# to change a pair (a,b) into pair (c,d) with conditions

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

We have two positive integers a and b .We need to change it into (c,d).We have a puzzle associated with this.

```
                You also have a red button and a blue button.

            Whenever you push the red button, both your numbers are incremented by 1.

           Whenever you push the blue button, both your numbers are multiplied by 2.
```

If there is a sequence of zero or more button pushes that accomplishes your goal, FIND the length of the shortest such sequence else say IMPOSSIBLE.
I came across this code which solves the above problem but could not get the logic right .

```
 int minimalSteps(int a, int b, int newA, int newB)
  {
 int p = 1, m = 0; //m is the number of *2 operations
const int INF = 2000000000;
int res = INF;
// fix p:
while ( (a <= newA/p) && (b <= newB/p) ) {
    int remA = newA - p*a;
    int remB = newB - p*b;

    if (remA == remB) { // must be equal
        // find the minimum number of +1 operations:
        int q = p;
        int y = remA;
        int tm = m;
        while (q > 0) {
            if (y >= q) {
                tm += y / q;
                y %= q;
            }
            q /= 2;
        }
        res = std::min(res, tm);
    }

    p = p * 2;
    m++;
}

return (res >= INF) ? -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  think about what happens to the difference between the two numbers when you press each button.  This will give you a necessary condition for it to be possible.

Comment: Also express $a$ in binary notation and see what the number looks like after a few button pushes.

Comment: Thus doesn't answer the question .

Comment: @satya:  I agree the binary is not helpful because of the add button.  I think my hint is quite useful.  Has it helped you?

Comment: @RossMillikan Can you explain things clearly now as i have posted the code .

Comment: @satya:   I don't understand the code, either.  You should be able to solve the problem by hand, then code the procedure.  It appears the code is just counting up the number of doublings, but one should be able to compute the number from $a,b,c,d$ directly.  Maybe they don't have a log function available, but this looks like C, which (I believe) does.